# How to deal with querying from multiple servers where some servers may be inactive

Tags: sql-server, timeout

I have a stored procedure that loops through a list of servers and queries their master DBs. When one of these servers is down, the stored procedure querying times out. How can I skip the querying of any inactive server, or, how can I catch the server timeout and continue to do the queries on the remaining active servers? I do have a Server table with an IsActive column, but the value is not automatically changed when a server goes down. Currently, the list of servers to query is based on this IsActive column in the table. Another solution could be to find a way to automatically change the IsActive column whenever a server goes down but I wouldn't know how to go about that. Any thoughts?

EDIT: I'm doing this all in SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do *not* do this from inside the engine (linked servers).

Query from an outside process. Launch the queries in parallel, with a [connection timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.connecttimeout.aspx) set. Your 'query' will get all the information at once and you will only have to wait *once for all servers that are down*, roughly, the timeout you've set, instead of *once for each server that is down*. I would recommend against 'testing' for the connectivity because attempting to connect **is** the test. If you would, say, iterate over the servers and call `sp_testlinkedserver` for each you risk waiting *more* in the end, because the tests are still serialized and they take the same amount of time as attempting to connect (this is what the test *does*, it attempts to connect).

A much better solution would be to use a reliable transport and asynchronous messaging instead, eg. [Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893.aspx). Since the programmign model is asynchronous but the messaging is reliable, it doesn't matter if a server is down, you will get the result you want later, when is finally back online.

Comment: I was suggesting sp_testlinkedserver for a background process that keeps the IsActive column up to date, not something to issue in each iteration during the actual stored procedure that is currently timing out.

Comment: @Aaron: a lot of context you left out from the original comment. But even then, I would advise against an 'IsActive' column because it will always run the risk of drifting apart from real state (at least between updates) and the query will still have to handle cases when the column says Yea but the network say Nay.

Comment: Sure, but for an architecture that is already in place, even a warmly reliable state using [sp_testlinkedserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189809.aspx) is an easier initial transition than moving wholesale to Service Broker, which isn't going to happen overnight.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @Remus, I'm going to mark your answer as correct since this is a great idea. Unfortunately, my requirements have changed such that I need to only query the server specified in the outer-most stored procedure, rather than all active ones. The stored procedure I'm working on is nested a couple levels deep so I suppose I'll need to pass the specific server down as a parameter. If there's a better way to do so then please let me know. But as far as the original question, your answer is great so thank you for that.

Comment: @WillWeld: passing the parameter down is the best option. there are ways to pass it out of band, like a #temp table or using [context info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189252(v=sql.105).aspx), but explicit parameters is the proper way.